# Is the order of SKNode.nodesAtPoint guaranteed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, sknode

`SKNode` has a method `nodesAtPoint` which returns an array of children nodes that intersect given point.  Is the order of the elements in such array deterministic (e.g. by drawing order)?

I could not find an answer in documentation, so probably the answer is "no", but I would like to verify.

Comment: I would assume they're ordered by z position, but if it isn't documented I wouldn't do anything that relies on a specific order.

Comment: Run a test yourself and find out.

Comment: It's fairly straightforward to sort the array in `zPosition` order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, Sprite Kit does not take into account z-position when traversing the node-tree (definitely for performance reasons). You can easily see this by adding a few nodes to a scene in-order and then changing the z-positions. The order will always be based on the position of the node within the node-tree, rather than the z-position.

Comment: Thanks.  I did some better tests myself, and it seems that the order is not always there at all.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov Yup, and if you have nodes with children it gets even more unpredictable.

Comment: Which means that there's some hash-table probably being used under the water, some dictionary I guess.  At any rate, I think have to do sorting on the result array.